# overloading a parent's method in php5

Tags: php, methods, overloading

I am struck at overloading the parent's class methods from an inherited child at level2.

```
abstract class parent
  -> child1 extends parent
    -> final class child2 extends child1
```

I want to overload the methods of `parent` in `child2`

```
abstract class Shape
{
    protected $length;
    protected $height;
    protected $a;
    protected $b;
    protected $c;
    public function getCoordinates($length,$height)
    {
        $this->length=$length;
        $this->height=$height;
    }
    public function getSides($a,$b,$c)
    {
        $this->a=$a;
        $this->b=$b;
        $this->c=$c;
    }

    abstract public function area();
    abstract public function perimeter();
    abstract public function display();

}

class rectangle extends Shape
{
    public function area()
    {
        return round(($this->length)*($this->height),2);
    }
    public function perimeter()
    {
        return round(2*(($this->a)+($this->b)),2);
    }
    public function display()
    {
        echo "area is :". rectangle::area() . "<br>";
        echo "perimeter is : ". rectangle::perimeter() ."<br>";
    }
}



final class triangle extends rectangle
{
    function __call($method_name, $arguments) // this is wrong ........please modify here to call area(),which is in shape class();
      {
          $accepted_methods = array("getCoordinates","area","perimeter");
      }

      public function area()
    {
        return round((($this->length)*($this->height)*($this->width)/2),2);
    }
    public function perimeter()
    {
        return round((($this->a)+($this->b)+($this->c)),2);
    }
    public function getCoordinates($length,$height,$width)
     {
         $this->length=$length;
         $this->height=$height;
        $this->width=$width;
      }
    public function display()
    {
        echo "area is :". triangle::area() . "<br>";
        echo "perimeter is : ". triangle::perimeter() ."<br>";
    }
 }


$r=new rectangle();
$r->getCoordinates(1,2,4);
$r->getSides(6,2);
$r->display();


$ot = new triangle();
$ot->getCoordinates(1,2,4);
$ot->getSides(6,2,3);
$ot->display();
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what's the question? Could you provide a simplified code sample?

Comment: Don't you know how to call methods from parent classes?

Comment: Also, "triangle extends rectangle". Now, I haven't studied geometry in a while, but that seems unlikely...

Comment: its an example, not pure geomentry mr.

Answer (score 0):

```
$r->getSides(6,2);
```

Your abstract class demands three arguments! Plus the function is actually a setter method. You should name it setSides();. Same with getCoordinates().

**Update**: I think you are confusing inheritance with overloading. Here is an example for overloading with __call. I assume that's not what you are trying to do but what you have in your example. Maybe this will help.

```
abstract class overloadTestAbstract {

    public function printOne($show) {
        echo __METHOD__ . ': ' . $show . '<br />';
    }

}

class overloadTestOne extends overloadTestAbstract {

    public function __call($method,$arguments) {
        $methods = array('printOne','printTwo','printThree');
        if ( in_array($method,$methods) ) {
            echo __METHOD__ . ' :OVERLOAD METHOD: ' . $arguments[0] . '<br />';
        } else {
            echo 'We are so sorry, but this method is available';
        }
    }

    public function printTwo($show) {
        echo __METHOD__ . ': ' . $show . '<br />';
    }

}
```

Then if you do this:

```
$test = new overloadTestOne();

$test->printOne('Hello World');
$test->printTwo('Goodbye World');
$test->printThree('Hello World, again');
$test->printFour('Goodbye World, again');
```

you will get this

```
// print results 
'overloadTestAbstract::printOne: Hello World'
'overloadTestOne::printTwo: Goodbye World'
'overloadTestOne::__call :OVERLOAD METHOD: Hello World, again'
'We are so sorry, but this method is available'
```

Although I have printOne and printTwo in the overload __call as accepted methods they are not used because these methods are already defined, they are handled by the existing methods as expected. On the other hand printThree gets overloaded because the method does not exist. Same with printFour but that method has no intend to print the argument. The array you have defined with the accepted methods doesn't do a thing. It is just an array. You have to assign some task to these methods or return some error like I did.

Comment: the question is simple:: how to OVERLOAD parent's methods from child class ...?? its not calling ........ i have to overload .....Mr felix king

Comment: You are calling methods getCoordinates() and getSides() twice! These methods already exist, defined in your abstract class. Overloading with __call has therefore no effect. __call() is triggered when invoking **inaccessible** methods in an object context. Your methods are accessible as much as I understand!